# Angular App Rewrite URL after App is loaded

Tags: angular, url, url-rewriting

I have a customer with a running angular app without the source code.  We are in the middle of re-writing the app, but there is an urgent need to change the content of one of the pages.

I have "saved as..." the page to get some raw HTML and I am able to load the page on the site.  Now, I need to be able to redirect any calls to the old page to the new page.  This works fine with a redirect rule with IIS if that page is the first page requested, but all other routes to that page are still handled by the Angular Router and the IIS rule is not used.

Is there any trickery that will allow me to bypass the Angular router for this one page?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to come across some javascript to do what I wanted.  It may not be 100% efficient or clean, but it only has to work for a little bit.  This goes in the index.html page.

```
<script>
var oldHref = document.location.href;

window.onload = function() {
var bodyList = document.querySelector("body")

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
            oldHref = document.location.href;
            
    if (document.location.href == "*yoursite*/*oldpage*"){
        window.location.replace("*yoursite*/*newpage*");
    }
        }
    });
});

var config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};

observer.observe(bodyList, config);
};

</script>
```